# Quantum Mechanics - Lowering Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

Let $a$ be a lowering operator.

Show that $a$ is a derivative respects to raising operator, $a^\dagger$, $$a = \frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}a^\dagger}$$

Can someone please explain how to prove the above statement?

Comment: Consider a polynomial in $A^\dagger$, $p(A^\dagger)$, then compute $[A, f(A^\dagger)]$ and $\frac{d}{dA^\dagger} f(A^\dagger)$...

Comment: I tried to solve it using the hints you give, but I get stuck. I don't see the relation of using the [A,f(A†)] in solving the question. And I am lost in how to apply df(A†)/dA†. @ValterMoretti

Comment: I think the answer makes the question even more sensible. In my opinion it is a fairly good question. It shouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 4):

Everything follows is valid at least when the various operators appearing below are defined on the dense subspace finitely spanned by the standard vectors $|n\rangle$, $n=0,1,2,\ldots.$

From $[a,a^\dagger]=I$ and $[A,BC]= B[A,C]+[A,B]C$, by induction,  one easily finds that
$$[a,(a^\dagger)^n] = n(a^\dagger)^{n-1}\:.$$
If $\alpha_k \in \mathbb C$ and $(a^\dagger)^{0}:=I$, linearity in the right-hand entry now implies that
$$\left[a, \sum_{n=0}^N \alpha_n (a^\dagger)^{n}\right] = \sum_{n=0}^N n\alpha_n (a^\dagger)^{n-1}\:.$$
That is the same as writing
$$\left[a, p(a^\dagger)\right] = \frac{dp(a^\dagger)}{da^\dagger}\:,$$
where 
$$p(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N \alpha_n x^n\:.$$
Extending this identity to non-polynomial functions $f$ is difficult because $a^\dagger$ is not *normal* and, consequently, the interpretation of $f(a^\dagger)$ cannot be provided by spectral theory.